# New and Delete using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand if the following code actually deletes an object from memory

During `delete z`  what is actually deleted?
Does the dynamically created integer x get deleted?
Does y and z get deleted also?

I've run the program and different values get output when I cout x y and z

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int* x = new int;

*x=1;

int* y = x;
int* z = y;

delete z;

return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming the variable x is no longer on the heap?

Comment: Yep, `delete` takes pointer to object, so none of `x`, `y` and `z` are no longer valid pointers on object.

Comment: Due to the way your variables are initialised, `z` contains the address returned by `new int`.   So `delete z` releases the dynamically allocated `int` that was allocated using `new int`.   Since `x` and `y` also contain that same address, `*x`, `*y`, and `*z` are now unusable (e.g. assigning `*x = 2` gives undefined behaviour).     There is actually no such thing as "heap memory" in C++  ("heap" is an implementation detail of some systems, and too many people conflate that to mean dynamically allocated memory in C++).

Comment: thanks for the feedback, was just a little confused  when i do *x = 2;
cout<<*x; after delete z it still gives me 2

Comment: `delete` doesn't mean memory immediately gets bad, it means in particular something like: hey, you can give this piece of memory to new allocations. So maybe after several `new` calls and doing some stuff with these objects, it will not contain `2` anymore. Anyway, it's a bad practice to access deleted objects.

Comment: thanks! didnt know c++ didnt immeaditely delete's stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values are houses built on lots on a street.

Pointers are street addresses (to lots) written on a piece of paper.  Sometimes these pieces of paper are also on lots.

`new int` goes to the runtime and asks it to find a new lot somewhere, subdivide it into a new property, zone it for development, then build an `int` house on it, then return the address of the new lot.

Copying the `int*` around just copies around the piece of paper with that address on it.  Burning it (having a variable `x` with the address in it go out of scope) has no effect on the actual "lot" or the `int` built on it.

Calling `delete` and passing it the street address asks the runtime to go to that log, demolish the `int` there, then dezone/desubdivide it for development.  The pointed-to-`int` is gone, but all other copies of the pointer address remain.  They are just now dangerous nonsense, and if you try to go to that address you could end up anywhere -- in another unrelated `int` house, in a parking lot of a mall since built there, in a rubble-strewn demolition site, or in the reactor of a nuclear plant built on that location after you dezoned it (and your attempt to write `7` there caused it to melt down).

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback,
does delete work on non pointer varaibles ?

like would delete &a demolish a property directly?

i assume this is dangerous to:

int a =0;
int b = 2;

b = a;
delete &a;  

cout<<b;

so b wont always give 2?

Comment: @afzel `&a` is a pointer value.  It however does not point at data created by `new`.  So the result is undefined behaviour (UB is anything from nothing, to a crash, to emailing your browser history to your contact list, to time travel.  Yes, C++ permits bugs to time travel; and some can actually do it.)